# AlertDialog setOnDismissListener not working

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My activity opens a dialog. When it closes I need the function `ReloadTable()` to be executed. So I am trying to use `setOnDismissListener` but its not getting triggered. Could someone please help what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transaction, null);
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(TransactionsList.this , R.style.dialogwithoutdim));
builder.setView(layout);
alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
        ReloadTable();
    }
});

builder.show();
```

Comment: This is the reason it doesn't work for you, probably: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18269965/89818

Answer (score 13):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements DialogInterface.OnCancelListener{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
       .....
       alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(this);
       alertDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to setOnCancelListener to the AlertDialog.Builder:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                this);
alertDialogBuilder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                dialogmenu = false;
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 4):

OK...I figured it out myself.

I had to implement `DialogInterface.OnCancelListener` and add the `onCancel()` method. It worked!

Comment: `setOnDismissListener` is only available from API 17, I guess that was your problem.

Comment: @YoannHercouet Actually, API level 1?! http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29

Comment: Only for set through AlerDialog.Builder. In AlertDialog it since API level 1.

Answer (score 4):

**Use following code**

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
                final View dailogView = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
                builder.setView(dailogView);
                final AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
                dialog.show();
```

**DismissListener**

```
 dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                   // your code after dissmiss dialog     
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case you should use `alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(listener)`,and `alertDialog.setOnDismissListener` works with `dismissDialog(id)`.

Comment: This does not work. I am not dismissing the dialog. I just expect the back button be pressed to dismiss the dialog... why would the dismiss not trigger?

Comment: @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
 dismissDialog(id)
  super.onBackPressed();
 }  Have you tried setOnCancelListener with back button pressed?

Comment: Create alertDialog alerDialog field and cancel by object in OnBackPressed() function : dialog.cancel();

Answer (score 2):

I found the real problem.

You should call .show in the dialog, not in the builder.

Try it :)