# setOnCancelListener and setOnDismissListener is not called for AlertDialog for back button pressed or touch outside

Tags: android

When

- Touch outside the dialog region
- Press on back button

I'm expecting `onDismiss` (Or `onCancel`) will be called. However, both of them are not called. May I know is there anything I'm missing? From [AlertDialog setOnDismissListener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525304/alertdialog-setondismisslistener-not-working), I thought `onCancel` will be called when I press back button. But it doesn't work for me. May I know is there anything I had missed out?

```
public class RateAppDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {
    public static RateAppDialogFragment newInstance() {
        RateAppDialogFragment rateAppDialogFragment = new RateAppDialogFragment();
        return rateAppDialogFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rate_app_dialog_fragment, null);

        Utils.setCustomTypeFace(view, Utils.ROBOTO_LIGHT_TYPE_FACE);

        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getSherlockActivity())            
        .setTitle("Love JStock?")
        .setView(view)
        // Add action buttons
        .setPositiveButton("Rate 5 stars \u2605", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Utils.showShortToast("Rate");
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Utils.showShortToast("No");
            }
        })
        .setNeutralButton("Later", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Utils.showShortToast("Later");
            }
        })
        .create();

        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Utils.showShortToast("Back button pressed?");
            }
        });

        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Utils.showShortToast("Back button pressed?");
            }
        });

        return dialog;
    }

}
```

---

```
    FragmentManager fm = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.findFragmentByTag(RATE_APP_DIALOG_FRAGMENT) != null) {
        return;
    }

    RateAppDialogFragment rateAppDialogFragment = RateAppDialogFragment.newInstance();
    rateAppDialogFragment.show(fm, RATE_APP_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
```

Comment: @pskink Do you test run on the code? It really work fine for you?

Comment: I use Log.d. No different. Neither toast nor logging message doesn't show up.

Comment: i run it with minimal setup - Builder with positive and negative buttons only, tested with 2.2 avd

Comment: @pskink you will encounter the problem, if you are using DialogFragment.

Comment: ok, see it now, but docs of onCreateDialog explain everything

Comment: Check this answer if you are working with newer android versions (I only tested on 7.1)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520597/android-illegalstateexception-you-can-not-set-dialogs-oncancellistener-or-on

Answer (score 171, accepted):

The problem happens when you are using `DialogFragment` to display `Dialog`

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html, the solution is to override `onCancel` in `DialogFragment`

Please take note from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle) too

> Note: DialogFragment own the Dialog.setOnCancelListener and
>   Dialog.setOnDismissListener callbacks. You must not set them yourself.
>   To find out about these events, override onCancel(DialogInterface) and
>   onDismiss(DialogInterface).

```
// This is DialogFragment, not Dialog
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
}
```

Comment: nice solution! It is actually the way to work with Cancel in DialogFragment.

Comment: it works if you leave `super.onCancel(dialog)`.. I am able to trigger my action right after, and `cancel` button doesn't end up having this method call which is good

Comment: @Cheok Yan Cheng I have a similar use case and set up onCancel() based on your recommendation above.  Sometimes it takes multiple clicks outside the dialog (I am using a DatePickerDialog within a DilaogFragment) for the dialog to finally dimiss.  Any ideas on how to capture the first touch outside the dialog so that I can dismiss the dialog immediately?

Comment: I have an AlertDialog inside a DialogFragment.

Both onCancel() and onDismiss() are called  in DialogFragment when I
a) backpress
b) press cancel button
c) or accept button on the AlertDialog

setOnCancelListener() is not allowed apparently on AlertDialog as it crashed at runtime.

Am a bit lost here.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using `AlertDialog`, see

```
builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // dialog dismiss without button press
    }
});
```

and `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)` (thanks @LeosLiterak)

Comment: and add dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true) as well

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can not set Dialog's OnCancelListener or OnDismissListener

Comment: Do not work either with builder (at least to me), tested on API 21.

Comment: @Joe That's because you're using it with `DialogFragment` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520597/illegalstateexception-you-can-not-set-dialogs-oncancellistener-or-ondismissli)). Use AlertDialog, it is working.

Comment: @VadimKotov For me AlertDialog is giving the exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {SomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can not set Dialog's OnCancelListener or OnDismissListener

Answer (score 5):

You have not set `backPressed` key event

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: But, how about touching outside the dialog box region? Also, you have idea why setOnCancelListener and setOnDismissListener doesn't work? They should work, isn't it?

Comment: As you got the solution. i'll say that was big and silly mistake.. :D its compulsory that if you are overriding the default method you have to right `@override` on it.

Answer (score 3):

you should read this topic: [How to dismiss the dialog with click on outside of the dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384067/how-to-dismiss-the-dialog-with-click-on-outside-of-the-dialog)

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context)
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

in your DialogFragment, override

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mListener != null) {
       // do something here
    }
}
```