# DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.onDismiss() is never called

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I created a Dialog with `AlertDialog.Builder` and set the `OnDismissListener` but `onDismiss()` is never called, no matter how I dismiss the Dialog. I need to know when the user dismissed the Dialog by touching the screen background.

Alternately, I would happy making it impossible to dismiss the Dialog by touching the screen background. I thought Builder.setCancelable(false) would do that but it doesn't.

Comment: Post the code for how you are setting the listener.

Comment: When you tap outside the dialog, it will *cancel* the dialog, so that is what you need to be dealing with. Neither of the two answers, below, worked for me - but this one worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269965/1617737

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, my best guess is that you need to implement **DialogInterface.OnCancelListener**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements DialogInterface.OnCancelListener{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
       .....
       alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(this);
       alertDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        .....
    }
}
```