# How to override onCancel in Dialog Fragment in Android in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, overriding, android-dialogfragment

I want to show a progress bar `DialogFragment`.
It would be shown until either it is cancelled or dismissed.
It can be cancelled if the user either presses back button or touches outside of the dialog, and is dismissed if the user doesn't cancel it before the completion of the task.
So, I want to set `listeners` for both so I can respond according to the case.
The dialog is being called from a `Fragment`.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269965/8455110), I can't set `listeners`, instead I have to `override` the methods.
My main problem is, I don't know how to do that in `kotlin`.
I have written some of the code below but it is incomplete. Please correct the code where needed.

I am trying to implement only `onCancel` for now. Please do tell if `onDismiss` is needed to be implemented in some different way.
Following the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23786151/8455110),
this is how I have coded the `Fragment`:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment(), DialogInterface.OnCancelListener {

    // other code

    private fun myFun() {
        // show progress dialog
        val myDialog = DialogProgress()
        myDialog.show(childFragmentManager, "null")

        // todo the long task of downloading something
        // myDialog.dismiss()
    }

    override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface?) {
        // User canceled the dialog
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Process canceled by user!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        // todo
    }

}
```

And this is my `DialogFragment` code:

```
class DialogProgress: DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface?) {
        super.onCancel(dialog)
        // need help here
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

        // show progress dialog
        val v = activity!!.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_progress, null)
        v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.progress_message).text = "Fetching data"

        return activity!!.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it, R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dialog)
            builder
                .setView(progressView)
                .create()
        }

    }
}
```

For the above code where I need help, I don't know how to convert the following `Java` code from the link of solution given above into `kotlin`:

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    Fragment parentFragment = getParentFragment();
    if (parentFragment instanceof DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) {
        ((DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) parentFragment).onDismiss(dialog);
    } 
}
```

Note that this is for `onDismiss`, I want it for `onCancel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java code can be simply converted into kotlin code by pasting it into the Android Studio and a pop-up should appear.
This is the conversion of the java code:

```
override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface?) {
    super.onCancel(dialog)
    val parentFragment = parentFragment
    if (parentFragment is DialogInterface.OnCancelListener) {
        (parentFragment as DialogInterface.OnCancelListener).onCancel(dialog)
    }
}
```